# is gsutil cp secure for uloading sensitive data

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm reading docs about how to use google cloud, particularly to store data on a bucket.

I can see the gcloud scp command to upload file to a VM in a secure way (highlighted in the doc).

To uload to a bucket, it's said to use gsutil cp

Is this command secure ? If I want to upload sensitive data, do I have to take more precautions (and how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil):

> By default, gsutil accesses Cloud Storage through JSON API request endpoints. You can change this default to the XML API.

The JSON API request endpoint is HTTPS - so assuming the security provided by HTTPS is sufficient for your needs, it should be fine. That won't guard against attacks if your local machine has been compromised with a bogus version of gsutil, but at that point all bets are probably off.

Comment: Actually, gsutil ships [with its own set of certificates from the boto library](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/cacerts/cacerts.txt). So even if your system level certificates are compromised, gsutil won't be. But if your local machine is compromised, gsutil could also be modified.

Comment: Thanks. I was not sure to have very well understood. Now I am.

Comment: Adding to this thread, the original documentation from Google. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/SecurityandPrivacyConsiderations